# Где реализовать вот такую игру/генератор карт

Tags: java, javafx, разработка-игр, реализация

Дали задание на реализацию генерации карты MxN клеток, в клетках соответственно располагаются какие то препятствия(есть ощущение что это потом перерастет в игру)
Интерфейс я реализую на javaFX, знаком с ним
Но где реализовать само графическое отображение такой карты, какая среда разработки, какой элемент? Причем нужно чтобы можно было мышкой эту карту "передвигать" и масштабировать
Подскажите пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужна генерация фиксированной карты вручную в спец. программе или случайной в самом коде игры?

Comment: Там должны быть параметры генерации, и на их основе

Comment: Ещё раз: вы хотите создать карту вручную, выбирая в какой клетке внутри MxN какой тип ландшафта будет, или вы хотите чтобы код сам карту сгенерировал (а научить его генерировать не просто кашу, а что-то осмысленное, будет непросто).

Comment: код сам должен генерировать

Comment: Вам что нужно понять как это делать или у вас есть код который не работает?

Comment: Я пока не приступал к коду, мне нужно понять где все это должно отображаться? сгенерированная карта

Comment: Сначала надо понять где она будет генериться, разве не так?

Comment: _"где все это должно отображаться"_ - в самой игре, вестимо. Покуда игры нет - в её прототипе, который, например, будет уметь только отображать карту. А если сгенерировать карту в формате, понятном какой-то программе для отображения карт, то открыть можно быть в этой программе. Только для этого нужно знать формат данных программы.

Comment: какие например? вот мой вопрос, куда выводить карту которую мой будущий код сгенерирует?

Comment: @Roman ответ на этот вопрос  вам уже дан: либо вы пишете свою "выводилку" карты, и тогда вы генерируете карту в каком вам нужно формате, либо вы используете стороннюю программу (например, Tiled) и генерируете карту в формате, понятном программе.

Comment: @Regent какой вопрос?

Comment: @RomanC пардон, промахнулся ником: уж больно они схожи...

Comment: @Roman Может Вам пригодится: [Jonathan Giles](https://jonathangiles.net/java-desktop-links-of-the-week-april-16-2/) недавно в своем блоге 
ссылочку давал на [FXGL (FX Game Library)](http://almasb.github.io/FXGL/).